# How to compile and run code from user in Java?

Tags: java, javac

How can I run a Java code, which user send me in request?

I need to take a code from user, that uses some of my classes, run it and take a result.

Comment: For starters: become extremely paranoid about security.

Comment: @LouisWasserman of course, but compile and run users code is the basis of my idea.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you compile the code in your program? It's a more common technique to provide an interface which users can program against, compile their own implementation, and then register their implementation (.jar file) with your program. This is how JDBC enabled programs work when you have to register a JDBC driver.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wants to build a code eval type application.

Comment: @Samuel are there some difference between compile user code and compile user implementation of my interface?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yes, somethink like eval in PHP or other languages.

Comment: I'm suggesting your program doesn't compile the code. I'm suggesting your user has to find a way to compile their own code. --Which if they know how to write Java in the first place, they probably know how to compile it.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind now I don't understand how to load code.

Ok, just simple example: there is a site with text field, user write to it "System.out.println("Hello World");" and send a request for my server.
And then my programm must run it and return result to user.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write your own [ideone](https://ideone.com/)

Comment: @azurefrog yes, something like this, but a game

Comment: @z17 What should happen when someone writes `java.lang.System.exit(1);` into the text field? Would this shutdown your whole server?

Comment: @RolandIllig security is another question, first of all i want to know how to run this code.

Comment: "Take a result" -- you mean from `java`'s stdout/stderr?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade doesn't matter. I think it is depends on the way.

But thanks, I have already find a solution, and is the same, as Roland Illig wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very crude way would be this:

```
String code = request.getParameter("code");
String className = "Code" + DigestUtils.sha1hex(code);
String classCode = ""
  + "public class " + className + " implements Runnable {\n" +
  + "  public void run() {\n" +
  + code + "\n"
  + "  }\n"
  + "}\n";
Files.write(new File(className + ".java"), code, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac " + className + ".java");

Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
((Runnable)clazz.newInstance()).run();
```

Assuming that the current directory is in the classpath, and further assuming that the classloader loads classes on-demand, this or something similar should work, at least for your `System.out` example.

When playing with this code, be aware that the uploaded code may do anything, including invoking `System.exit(1)`, reading all the files in the filesystem, starting a botnet on the computer, and so on.

Instead of the last two lines of code, you could also do:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java " + className);
```

(Or some variation of it, which then allows you to capture `System.out` and `System.err`, so you can feed them back to the HTTP client. This would also prevent any danger from `System.exit`, so that only the numerous other vulnerabilities are left.)

Comment: I've done it already, like you write in the second way.Thank you.

Comment: About security: it is possible to run this code in some container, where nobody can't do somethink bed.

Also I have read about Java Compile API, but didn't try yet.